# Toggle jsf components without backing beans?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

How can I use (eg ajax) to show a specific jsf element if I click the button where the ajax tag belongs to? But without having to use any backing bean, just by JSF components without JavaScript?
Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, but it sounds more like a JavaScript work, not ajax. Why would you want to go to the server just to make actions that can be handled on client side?

Comment: Luiggi is right , but if you want , I think you can bind like this `<h:inputText id="first" binding="#{someViewButNonManagedBeanObject}"`... and than `<h:inputText id="second" render="#{not empty someViewButNonManagedBeanObject}"`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luiggi is right , You better use js for client side toggling

But ,
I think you can bind like this

```
<h:inputText id="first" binding="#{someViewButNonManagedBeanObject}"`...
```

and than

```
<h:inputText id="second" render="#{no empty someViewButNonManagedBeanObject}"`...
```

or

```
<h:inputText id="second" render="#{someViewButNonManagedBeanObject.value eq 'wow'}"`...
```

**(Not tested)**